# Why do we not have to await futures for Hive in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Hive [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/hive#usage) says:

> You can use Hive just like a map.
> It is not necessary to await Futures.

```
var box = Hive.box('myBox');
box.put('name', 'David');
var name = box.get('name');
print('Name: $name');
```

How come we don't have to await?

If the device is running slow, is there no risk that the `put` and `get` commands will run before the `box` was opened?

My understanding was that you had to use `await` or risk some hard to troubleshoot timing issues.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hive, but presumably `put`/`get` operate on a local data structure with already-loaded values and therefore can be synchronous. Skimming over the documentation, [`Hive.box`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/HiveInterface/box.html) returns an already existing `Box`, in contrast to [`Hive.openBox`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/HiveInterface/openBox.html) which loads data from storage and returns a `Future`.  Similarly, [`Hive.save`](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/HiveInterface/openBox.html) also returns a `Future`.

Answer (score 1):

**From Hive Docs -**

You may wonder why writing works without async code. This is one of the main strengths of Hive.

The changes are written to the disk as soon as possible in the background but all listeners are notified immediately. If the async operation fails (which it should not), all listeners are notified again with the old values.

If you want to make sure that a write operation is successful, just await its `Future`.

Comment: This sounds amazing, but goes against everything I know about async programming. If you don't await you could get all sort of intermittent problems when a device is running slow for example. Normally the operation takes only a few milliseconds, but today it takes 500. You put, then get without await and you get a null because put has not committed. It just seems risky.

Answer (score 0):

The 'official' benchmark utility will show you that write operations are order of magnitude slower than read.

For example (on a random Android tab, in release mode): Read, String, 20K records: 192ms vs Write, String, 20K records: 22,509ms.

So, as a best practice, I await write operations, but do not await read.

Remember that even in non-async operations, say you are performing extremely complex logic on a very large array of Strings - this can take time, can't it? How do you think flutter handles this? There is no await...

Comment: If you are performing a long sync operation, the execution will wait until it is finished. For async you typically have an option to wait or not wait. If you don't wait it is fire an forget. E.g. you are writing info to a log you can fire and forget, as in you don't care if it succeeded or not. But with writing and reading values to a local database, you do want to make sure that the value was written before trying to read it